# Spring Social Rember me login

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social

How can I get Spring Social to have a remember me function using facebook and twitter login that's similar to remember-me login using form based login in Spring Security?

I'm using Spring Social 1.0.0.RC2 and Spring Security 3.0.5.RELEASE.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt, if it is then it will be till the OAuth token timeout,.

Answer (score 5):

I have an example app that has the code for this here:

https://github.com/sdouglass/spring-security-social

The way I did it was to call Spring Security's TokenBasedRememberMeServices.onLoginSuccess(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Authentication) in my Spring Social SignInAdapter implementation.

https://github.com/sdouglass/spring-security-social/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/security/social/web/SignInAdapterImpl.java

[TokenBasedRememberMeServices JavaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.html#onLoginSuccess%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20org.springframework.security.core.Authentication%29)

[SignInAdapter JavaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/social/connect/web/SignInAdapter.html)

Comment: How can I do this without using spring social. Specifically without SignInAdapter class, how do I get an handle on the HttpServletRequest and Response?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. You want to have "remember me" support using only Spring Security? That should be fine, as the TokenBasedRememberMeServices are a part of Spring Security, not Spring Social. You should be able to find all the info you need in the "remember me" section of the Spring Security docs, e.g. http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/remember-me.html

Comment: From what I understood. I need to write my own impl of RememberMeAuthenticationFilter so that I get access to the ServletRequest and response and call tokenBasedRememberMeServices.onLoginSuccess?

Comment: I think you can use Spring provided implementations, or so it seems to me from this section of the docs: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/remember-me.html#d0e4282

Comment: I only had to do something different from the Spring Security docs because I was trying to use both Spring Security AND Spring Social.